# how to capture response data in jmeter and do parameterisation

Tags: java, json, csv, jmeter, response

I'm testing a standalone java application using JMeter and I'm using a OS Process Sampler to execute the jar file. I've given JSON string in java program and I've used publish method to post JSON string to Queue. Now I want to capture the data in JMeter response data and I want to do parameterisation for those fields and I want to use CSV Data Set Config to pass the values to fields and each user should take unique data.

The JSON string looks like below and I want to parameterise these valuse from JMeter response data and pass values from CSV file.

```
[{
"id": 100001,
"status": "Pending",
"priorityCode": "1",
"miniTeamId": "234256",
"requestName": "General"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
100001,Pending,1,234256,General
100002,Done,2,234257,General
etc.
```

Configure your CSV Data Set config as follows:

- Filename: path to your .csv file (better full path)
- Variable Names: `id,status,priorityCode,miniTeamId,requestName`

  [image: CSV Data Set Config]

other fields can be left as they are. By default JMeter will read next line from CSV file by each thread on each loop, when file end will be reached - JMeter will start over.

[JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) populated by the CSV Data Set Config can be referred as `${variableName}` or `${__V(variableName)}` so parametrised request body should look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": ${id},
    "status": "${status}",
    "priorityCode": "${priorityCode}",
    "miniTeamId": "${miniTeamId}",
    "requestName": "${requestName}"
  }
]
```

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) for more detailed information on parametrisation of JMeter tests using CSV files.

Also be aware of the following test elements:

- [__csvRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function - if you need to get data from multiple CSV files
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - if you need to get values from response JSON

---

UPD: passing parametrized JSON string via OS Process Sampler

[image: OS Process Sampler]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please let me know where should I enter the parametrised request body?

Comment: Switch [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "Body Data" and paste parametrised body there

Comment: I already did that but this application doesn't have any url so we can't use HTTP sampler. Is there any other way to achieve my scenario?

Comment: How do you pass non-parametrized JSON?

Comment: I passed JSON in the java program and then converted that program to JAR file.

Comment: In that case just pass this JSON string as an argument in the OS Process sampler

Comment: How can I pass JSON Strubg in OS Process Sampler?

Comment: Updated my initial answer with the demo, see [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for detailed explanation if needed

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will work on it. If I face any problem will get back to you.